# One rpc connection faster than another

Tags: events, rpc

I have four synced peer nodes running on two separate machines. Nodes 1-3 have been around since the beginning of the block chain and are all on one machine while Node 4 was just added around block 36000 and is on a separate machine.

Nodes 1 and 4 have open rpc ports and I am connecting to them through Metamask. When I run functions that use pastEvents, Node 4 responds noticeably faster than Node 1.

Why is this?
What could be causing Node 1 to return event data so slowly (much slower than Node 4) ?